# Problems while compiling XDR on macOS (RPC types.h issue)

Tags: c, macos, unix, rpc, xdr

I am trying to compile some source codes about UNIX scokets programs, on Linux I have no problems but on macOS I get stuck in front of types definition problems. I don't know how many details I can put here, but I'll try.

The source codes to be compiled are:

```
errlib.c
errlib.h
server_test.c
sockwrap.c
sockwrap.h
```

where the `main` is located in `server_test.c`.

To compile I use:

```
gcc -Wall -DTRACE -o server_test server_test.c errlib.c sockwrap.c
```

There are no problems running this on Linux, but on macOS I get more than 20 error and all of these are about a (perhaphs) missing definition of `bool_t`. I suppose something not working in `/usr/include/rpc/*` files located in macOS internal libraries.

So I looked for if `<sys/types.h>` is included in `/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h` and it seems to be not missing.

Some of the first lines of the `gcc` output are:

```
In file included from server_test.c:16:
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:126:3: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
                bool_t  (*x_getlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, int *);
                ^
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:126:10: error: function cannot return function type 'int (struct __rpc_xdr *, int *)'
                bool_t  (*x_getlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, int *);
                        ^
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:128:3: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
                bool_t  (*x_putlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, const int *);
                ^
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:128:10: error: function cannot return function type 'int (struct __rpc_xdr *, const int *)'
                bool_t  (*x_putlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, const int *);
                        ^

/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:128:3: error: duplicate member 'bool_t'
                bool_t  (*x_putlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, const int *);
                ^
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:126:3: note: previous declaration is here
                bool_t  (*x_getlong)(struct __rpc_xdr *, int *);
                ^
/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h:136:3: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
                bool_t  (*x_getbytes)(struct __rpc_xdr *, char *, unsigned int);
...
```

and many others lines that are very similar.

For those who want to deepen, the sources are available [here](https://gitlab.com/cristiano-c/socket-server-test).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

### The bad answer

Issue solved by simply including `<rpc/types.h>` in the `server_test.c` source as follows:

```
#include <rpc/types.h>
```

---

### The better one

This is a solution above is valid only for this `server_test.c` implementation.

If you want fix this issue *"globally"*, you can follow follown steps:

- disable SIP (how to? [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11))
- get your macOS's `xdr.h` (from here `/usr/include/rpc/xdr.h`)
- copy it elsewhere two times: one copy is for backup and modify the other one simply adding the required include (`#include <rpc/types.h>` and see the picture below)
- overwrite your modified `xdr.h` onto the original one in `/usr/include/rpc/`
- re-enable SIP

Here is how I did it:

[image]